# File manager project (creates and prints file)

Tags: beginner, c, file

I just finished my very simple and beginner-friendly C project and wanted to hear your thoughts and opinions about ways to improve it or something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getFile();
void createFile();

int main()
{
    createFile();
    getFile();
    return 0;
}

void createFile()
{
    char userfilename[40];
    char filecontent[1000];
    FILE *filePointer;

    printf("How do you want to name your file? ");
    scanf("%s", userfilename);
    filePointer = fopen(userfilename, "w");

    printf("Enter file content: ");
    scanf ("%999[^\n]", filecontent);
    getchar();
    fgets (&filecontent, 1000, stdin);
    fputs(filecontent, filePointer);

    fclose(filePointer);
    printf("Written file successful.\n");
}

void getFile()
{
    int c;
    char fileName[100];
    FILE *filePointer;

    printf("\nEnter filename: ");
    gets(fileName);
    printf("\n");

    filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(filePointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        printf("File contents:\n");
        while ((c = getc(filePointer)) != EOF)
        {
            putchar(c);
            if(c == ' ')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("Number of words: %d", count + 1);
        fclose(filePointer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is how the actual indentation looks? Remember this site eats the first four spaces you type.

Comment: Yeah I know! I have indented the code correctly in my IDE but this site is always giving me trouble when I input code as I then have to manually push some parts of the code 4 spaces right. Will edit it! thx

Comment: It's simple: Paste it as you have it, then mark it all and select the code-button `{}` or press ctrl+k to mark as code.

Comment: Oh thank you!!! It was driving me nuts lol

Answer (score 2):

Nice first question. It can definitely be expanded on for additional learning in the future.

**Improve Error Handling**

Both the functions `createFile()` and `getFile()` could be changed to return int. This would allow the program to exit with the correct status.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int createFile();                 // return EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE
int getFile();                    // return EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE

int main()
{
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;    // EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE are defined in stdlib.h

    status = createFile();
    if (status != EXIT_SUCCESS)
    {
        return status;
    }

    status = getFile();

    return status;
}
```

In `getFile()` the variable `filePointer` is tested after fopen(). This is a good practice. In `createFile()` the variable `filePointer` is not tested, this is a bad practice. The C library function fopen() for `write` can fail for a number of reasons:

- File exists and is protected.
- File exists and it is a directory.
- The program doesn't have sufficient privilege to write to the target directory.

There are more ways it can fail, this is a partial list. See [full list of possible error codes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html). The C library function [perror()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_perror.htm) can be used to report program error in the case of
I/O failures or the include file `errno.h` can be included and the global variable errno will contain
the error code for better error messages as shown in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633909/what-is-the-reason-for-fopens-failure-to-open-a-file).

These same error messages can be used to improve the error reporting in `getFile()` as well.

The existing error message in `getFile()` might be improved by adding the file name to the error message.

```
fprintf(stderr, "File %s not found.\n", fileName);
```

Error messages should generally be reported using `fprintf(stderr, FMT);` rather than reporting the error
to `stdout` using printf().

**Inconsistent File Name Size**

In `getFile()` fileName can be up to 99 characters (strings must be null terminated),
in `createFile()` it can be 39 characters, this is inconsistent and may confuse the user.
The code also doesn't tell the user how long the file name can be and that could be a
problem for the user. In neither case is the length of the string checked prior to use,
and that could lead to a number of errors including buffer overflow.

A better way to handle the file name size might be to define a symbolic constant using `#define`.

```
#define MAX_FILE_SPEC_LENGHT 1024

    char userfilename[MAX_FILE_SPEC_LENGHT];

    char fileName[MAX_FILE_SPEC_LENGHT];
```

The file name variable should be large enough to handle a full path as well as the file name.

Many systems define the maximum file name size based on the file system implementation. On Linux the
include file [linux/limits.h defines that maximum file name size using PATH_MAX](https://www.systutorials.com/qa/1504/maximum-allowed-file-path-length-for-c-programming-on-linux). Most operating systems
will have some way of defining it.

**Possible Bug**

This line was flagged by my C compiler with a warning:

```
    fgets (&filecontent, 1000, stdin);
```

The warning is Incompatible pointer types passing `char (*)[1000]` to parameter of type `char *`.
Since file content is an array of chars it only needs the name `filecontent` rather than the address
of `filecontent`, to use the address, it should be `&filecontent[0]`.

**Inconsistent Variable Naming Conventions**

In the function `createFile()` there are 3 variables, userfilename, filecontent and filePointer,
the variable filePointer is camelCase and is clear, userfilename and filecontent are not camelCase
and not quite as clear.